# ¿Como comparar una palabra ingresada desde el teclado con el contenido de un archivo .txt en JAVA?

Tags: java

Estoy realizando un programa el cual debe comparar una palabra ingresada desde la consola, con lo que hay en un archivo .txt 
por ejemplo, yo ingreso "Hola Mundo", y en mi archivo .txt esta "Hola Mundo", debe de decirme el programa que el texto es igual, y si no, me debe de decir que el texto no es igual. Estoy intentando compararlo con equals pero me dice que el texto no es igual aun cuando escribo exactamente lo que hay en mi .txt

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AbrirArchivostxt {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String texto = "";
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Dame una frase");
    texto = leer.nextLine();
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("Archivo.txt");
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(fr);
        if (texto.equals(bf)) {
            System.out.println("El texto es igual");
        } else {
            System.out.println("El texto no es igual");
        }
    } catch (Exception err) {
        System.out.println(err.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te ocurre es que nunca lees del fichero de texto por lo que nunca va a ser igual un string a nada. No puedo comprobarlo ahora mismo, pero diría que te falta esto para que te funcione.

```
 import java.io.*; 
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class AbrirArchivostxt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String texto = "";
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Dame una frase");
        texto = leer.nextLine();
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("Archivo.txt");
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String st; 
            while ((st = bf.readLine()) != null){             
                if (texto.equals(st)) {
                    System.out.println("El texto es igual");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("El texto no es igual");
                  }
            }
        } catch (Exception err) {
            System.out.println(err.getMessage());
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Amigo funciono correctamente muchas gracias con la ayuda!, serias tan amable de explicarme que es lo que hace esta linea while ((st = bf.readLine()) != null)

Comment: Es un bucle el cual no parará mientras haya algo que leer en el fichero, y la linea que va leyendo es la que introduce en st y la cual luego ves que comparas dentro de la función equals.

Comment: Te agradezco infinitamente amigo gracias :)